# Share a link, using custom image; from within an android application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I would like implement a feature in my live wallpaper application that allows a user to post a screenshot of his/her wallpaper, along with a link to the play store listing of my application.

As far as the non-facebook part goes, everything is in order.
I am able to make my engine draw a frame to a bitmap and have it save the bitmap to a file.

Where I am completely lost, is implementing the Facebook part...

I have the login part all setup (checks if user is already logged in, if not it asks for credentials, if yes it directly loads the selection.xml fragment as described in the tutorial.)
My personalized selection.xml even includes an imageview displaying the screenshot and an edit text for the user to name their screenshot (along with the user's name and profile picture).

Where do I go from there?
Apparently I have to make a webpage and program a custom open graph in javascript/css/html5?

I'm sure I have to be mistaken... It can't be that complicated... I just want to post a picture with a link, and maybe some text (NOT EVEN NECESSARY!)

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the object and story on the fly with an http call, but you will need to host the image somewhere.